# Trying to create a database in PSQL from the command line

Tags: postgresql, macos, command-line, psql

I have been trying to create a simple test database from my terminal by running the command 'createdb test'. I installed PostgreSQL using brew on my Mac OS. I have attached an image of the error message I get. I also tried adjusting the pg_hba.conf file using nano from my terminal but that didn't work.

[image: this is the error I get in my terminal]

Comment: Did you restart the postgres-server after changing pg_hba.conf?

Comment: You obviously provided the wrong password for the user `krubelsahle`

Comment: @FrankHeikens how do I restart the Postgres server from my terminal? I used the following command to start the server: brew services start postgresql. Then I used the following command to stop it: brew services stop postgresql.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The thing is I never created a password for that user so I don't know why it is asking me for a password. I tried using the same password as my Mac OS login but that didn't work.

Comment: What happens when you use database user "postgres" to connect? psql postgres

Comment: How do you restart postgresql:   `brew services restart postgresql`

Comment: Can you do `psql postgres`?

Answer (score 0):

thats because the user "krubelsahle" does not have password or you used a worng one.

try createdb "yourdbname" -U postgres and use the basic password or none

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).